# Asking for user input in long running operation

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have an application where a user can backup/restore his files to/from a server.

During the restore operation, before downloading each file, I check if the file already exists (assuming I know the original path).

`boolean fileExists(String path);`

If the file exists, I want to ask the user if he wishes to download and rename, download and replace, or skip the current file.

This could be a custom `AlertDialog` for example (using `AlertDialog.Builder` and an xml layout).

So the code would be something similar to:

```
static final int DECISION_NO_ANSWER = -1;
static final int DECISION_RENAME = 0;
static final int DECISION_REPLACE = 1;
static final int DECISION_SKIP = 2;

int userDecision;

for (RestoreFile file : ListOfFiles) {
    userDecision = DECISION_NO_ANSWER;
    if (fileExists(file.getOriginalPath())){
        OptionsDialog.show();
        // wait for answer
    }

    switch(userDecision){
        // handle different cases and update ProgressBar
    }
}
```

Of course this code should be running in a separate thread.

If I use an `AsyncTask` here's how I would wait for the answer:

```
while(userDecision == DECISION_NO_ANSWER){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
```

If I use a `Thread` I could use wait() and notify(). I would have to use a `Handler` to update the `ProgressBar`.

So which is better (`AsyncTask` or `Thread`) ? or is there a third better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An asynctask is run in a thread, like everything. you can use wait and notify, with a handler or the onProgressUpdate to notify the progressBar and everything.

Comment: which question are you answering?

Comment: [Calling wait in AsyncTask raises IllegalMonitorStateException](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/4f0Wu7KZEeU)

Comment: asynctask is fine, since you need to interact with the UI. It behave like (and is run in) a thread, so you can use wait and notify in the asynctask

Comment: @Benito : thanks, but as you can see, the issue is the developer you quote doesn't know how to use wait. it has to be synchronized.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I guess I didn't read through the whole thing. In that case would you say both methods give the same result?

Comment: I recommend asynctask for several reasons : 1/ it handles some interaction with the UI for you. 2/ it is run in a thread from a pool that has limited size, thus making sure that there won't be thousands of threads running at the same time.